# apache beam construct new column in csv file with header

Tags: csv, apache-beam-io

I am new to apache beam, trying to add new column to the csv file.
Hear is the input and output that I was expecting. Having issues splitting the data between header and data records.

Input csv file

```
col1,col2,col3
abc,456,sam
```

Output csv file

```
col1,col2,col3,extract_date
abc,456,sam,2023-05-11
```

when applied following code beam is processing data multiple times. Seems the filter that I have is not working as expected. Any suggestions would be of great help.

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromText, WriteToText
import datetime

class AddExtractDateColumn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        yield element + ',extract date'

class AddDateInfo(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        current_date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        yield element + ',' + current_date

with beam.Pipeline() as pipeline:
    # Read the CSV file
    lines = pipeline | 'Read CSV file' >> ReadFromText('input_file.csv')

    # Add the "extract date" column to the header record
    header_with_date = (
            lines
            | 'Extract Header' >> beam.ParDo(AddExtractDateColumn())
    )

    # Add the date information to the data records
    records_with_date = (
            lines
            | 'Skip Header' >> beam.Filter(lambda element: element != header_with_date)
            | 'Add Date Info' >> beam.ParDo(AddDateInfo())
    )

    # Combine the header record and the data records
    output = (
            (header_with_date, records_with_date)
            | 'Combine Output' >> beam.Flatten()
    )

    # Write the output to a new CSV file
    output | 'Write to CSV' >> WriteToText('output_file.csv')
```

Output from the above code :

```
col1,col2,col3,extract date
abc,456,sam,extract date
col1,col2,col3,2023-06-28
abc,456,sam,2023-06-28
```

Comment: Implemented by skipping the header record while processing the csv file and adding the header record back to the file with "header" option in "WriteToText". But the issue is I have to hard code the header values in the "Header" option. I tried passing that as a parameter value but it didn't worked. No error but in the file i am seeing the value like this "RuntimeValueProvider(option: file_header, type: str, default_value: None)" in place of the header record.